# How to get location of nearby bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, location

I tried to search many articles for the same, but couldn't find any related answer.

Can anyone help me with 'Is it possible to get the location of the nearby Bluetooth devices available'?

Answer (score 0):

No. At the most you may get their perceived signal strength but that alone will not be that helpful.